# dc.js coloring a stacked barChart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have 2 groups from the same dimension in barChart. I want to specify colors for these 2 groups. How can I achieve this?

```
bChart.dimension(time).group(Buyer).stack(Seller)
```

If shows default colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got this working. I was thrown off by the renderlet being deprecated and couldnt understand what `<renderletkey>` meant.

```
bChart.on("renderlet", function(chart){
chart.selectAll("g.stack rect.bar").attr("fill", function(d){
  if(d.layer=="Buyer")
      return "red";
  else
    return "blue";
});
```

However I still see the default colors for a flash till the renderlet is done processing? Is there a way to skip this.

Comment: You should use "pretransition" instead of "renderlet", it fires immediately, before the transitions. And yes, you shouldn't have to worry about the renderletkey unless you have multiple event handlers for the same event.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Works like a charm. I had to change `attr` to `style` in the function. Also the bars weren't dimming on selecting a subset of bars with slider. Thankfully I got a solution here. [last comment on the issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/200)